# Non constant member function being called inside a constant member function

Tags: c++, constants, member-functions

```
#include <iostream>

class Hello {
public:
    void Test() {
        std::cout << "Testing" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Hi {
public:
    Hi()
    :hello(new Hello())
    {}

    ~Hi()
    {
        delete hello;
    }

    void Testing() const {
        hello->Test();
    }

private:
    Hello  * hello;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    Hi hi; ;
    hi.Testing();
    return 0;
}
```

As i know a non-constant member function cant be called inside a constant member function but how the above code has been compiled successfully and giving the expected result .

Comment: This definitely doesn't compile.

Comment: @Rapptz::Now it compiles successfully .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `Hi::Testing`, the `hi` object "is const". Which means the pointer `hello` can't be modified inside that method. (It is as if `hello` had been defined as `Hello * const hello;` for the duration of that method.)

But this doesn't mean that `hello` is transformed into a pointer-to-const (which would look like `Hello const *  const hello;`). The object pointed to by `hello` isn't const, so you can invoke its non-const methods without restriction.

Comment: But it does not mean hello is  a constant object . But i have read like we cant call a non constant member function through constant object . Then in this case it violates the concept right ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `this` "is const" inside that method, and all members act as if they had a top-level const added. This means that pointer members become const-pointers. I.e. you couldn't do `hello = new Hello;` inside that method. That's all that const gives you though. It doesn't make all objects pointed-to by member pointers const.

Comment: all members act as if they had a top-level const added. This means that pointer members become const-pointers.
Can you please explain this line stated by you  little bit more ?

Comment: Yes, const pointers. Not pointers to const objects (or const pointers to const objects). The thing that "becomes const" is the pointer, not the object that the pointer points to. (In other words, `hello->foo()` does not modify the pointer `hello`, it only reads it, and then calls a method on the object that `hello` points to. That object did not "become const".)

Comment: I understood something from your post .But one thing i want to know is we have not declared hello as constant (Hello *const hello ) inside Hi class , then how Testing member function will take it as constant pointer  . OR is there any c++ concept on this topic which i am not aware of since i am very new to it .

Comment: The `const` you put in that function's signature (`void Testing() const`) is what makes the compiler process all the code inside that function _as if_ there was a top-level const added to all members of `Hi`. That's what the C++ standard says must be done for const-qualified member functions.

Comment: :: Thanks . Now i got it .
whenever we are declaring some member function as constant all the members present inside that function scope will be taken as constant . Like here hello is a constant pointer . so if we do something like hello = new Hello() inside Testing() , then it will give one error (since we are changing the address). But here we are trying to access what hello points to (that is Test()) , So its not showing any error . Is my understanding correct ? Please correct if i am wrong .

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the problem to the following situation:

```
Foo x;

Foo       *       p1 = &x;
Foo       * const p2 = &x;

p1->non_const_method();     // OK
p2->non_const_method();     // OK

Foo const *       q1 = &x;
Foo const * const q2 = &x;

q1->non_const_method();     // error
q2->non_const_method();     // error
```

Whether or not your `Hi`-object is constant only affects the *top-level* `const` modifier in this analogy (i.e. whether `Hi::hello` is `Hello *` or `Hello * const`). However, the *first* const modifier is an integral part of the pointer type itself (and unaffected by the constness of your object).

Comment: But here we have not declared Hello *const hello inside Hello class  then how it can take hello as constant ?

Comment: @Learner: You have to be more precise with your language. Your `Hi::Hello` is a `Hello *`, and in a constant object it is a `Hello * const`. But the pointer type is *never* `Hello const *`.

Comment: @fish: could you please add your edit as a comment instead? I'm not entirely sure whether it was an improvement...

Comment: @KerrekSB Sure, but which part of my edit do you think was incorrect? Also, in the current revision it is not clear what you mean by "top-level" (as it wasn't clear what you meant by "first" and "second" in the first revision).

Comment: I understood something from your post .But one thing i want to know is we have not declared hello as constant (Hello *const hello ) inside Hi class , then how Testing member function will take it as constant pointer  . OR is there any c++ concept on this topic which i am not aware of since i am very new to it .

Comment: @Learner: Any data member of an object becomes `const`-qualified when the object itself is `const`. Does that make sense? So if you have `struct X { int a; }; X const x;`, then `x.a` is a `int const`.

Comment: @KerrekSB::Thanks . Now i got it .
whenever we are declaring some member function as constant all the members present inside that function scope will be taken as constant . Like here hello is a constant pointer . so if we do something like hello = new Hello() inside Testing() , then it will give one error (since we are changing the address). But here we are trying to access what hello points to (that is Test()) , So its not showing any error . Is my understanding correct ? Please correct if i am wrong .

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer to a const object, that will restrict you to calling const member functions in the target object.

A const pointer to a (normal) object just means you can't modify the pointer itself. Since it's still a pointer to a normal object, you can use any member function, not just const member functions. If the target object has const and normal overloads of that function, the normal overload will be chosen.

When you have a pointer as a member of a const object, you get the second, not the first.